# Function is not being executed when split into multiple functions

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I am writing a script using casperJS and I have this function:

```
Extractor.prototype.get_links       = function() {                                                                                                                
    var links   = document.querySelectorAll('p.title a');                                                                                                         
    return Array.prototype.map.call(links, function(element) {                                                                                                    
        return element.getAttribute('href');                                                                                                                      
    });                                                                                                                                                           
};
```

which works fine and I get the desired result.  But when I try to create a new function and call it, like so:

```
function test_this() {
    var links   = document.querySelectorAll('p.title a');                                                                                                         
    return Array.prototype.map.call(links, function(element) {                                                                                                    
        return element.getAttribute('href');                                                                                                                      
    });
};

Extractor.prototype.get_links       = function() {
    test_this();
};
```

This is my casper.start method:

```
casper.start(webpage, function() {                                                                                                                                        
    var extractor   = new Extractor();                                                                                                                                    
    links  = links.concat(this.evaluate(extractor.get_links));
});
```

It seems that the function is not being called, and I do not get the desired result.  I am new to casperJS and javascript, and I cannot seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I made an edit to my post

Answer (score 0):

[`casper.evaluate`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluate) is sandboxed. It is the interface to the page context. Variables defined outside of the page context are not accessible outside.

In your case `test_this` is defined outside of the page context. You could define it through a separate `evaluate` if you really want this separation:

```
casper.start(webpage, function() {
    this.evaluate(function(){
        function test_this() {
            var links   = document.querySelectorAll('p.title a');                                                                                                         
            return Array.prototype.map.call(links, function(element) {          
                return element.getAttribute('href');                                                        
            });
        }
    });

    var extractor   = new Extractor();
    links  = links.concat(this.evaluate(extractor.get_links));
});
```